# Почему в LogCat выводятся всего две сообщении о создании обьектов, в то время как обьектов создано целых 200 штук?

Tags: java, android, logcat

```
public class Army {

    public static int soldiersCount;

    public Army(){
        if (soldiersCount<25)
        soldiersCount+=5;else soldiersCount++;
        Log.i("Room8000","new Army object is created");
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Army> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<200; i++){
            arrayList.add(new Army());
        }

        Log.i("Room8000","now the size of Army is "+Army.soldiersCount);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
2020-04-21 22:06:46.526 9344-9344/com.example.android.javaoop I/Room8000: new Army object is created
2020-04-21 22:06:46.530 9344-9344/com.example.android.javaoop I/Room8000: new Army object is created
2020-04-21 22:06:46.530 9344-9344/com.example.android.javaoop I/Room8000: now the size of Army is 220
```

Интересно, почему всего 2 раза сработала Log ?

Кстати пробовал и без цикла. Просто взять и написать несколько new Army(). Вначале создал всего один обьект. Log сработал один раз (Логично). Второй раз создал две обьекты. Log сработал два раза (Логично). Потом попробовал создать три обьекта. Log сработал всего два раза (НЕ ЛОГИЧНО). И опять в тупик.

Что с Log - ом не так?

Comment: а вы попробуйте soldiersCount в Log вставить

Comment: и лучше вставить его в тег

Comment: Воспользуйтесь debugger'ом и посмотрите пошагово что происходит. В целом код явно работающий, хоть и бессмысленный